# JMX confuse(remote server control)

Tags: java, remoting, jmx

I have a couple of **Tomcat** and **Glassfish** servers.

And i want to manage them over [**JMX**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/). "Use [JConsole](http://www.openjdk.org/tools/svc/jconsole/index.html)" - you could say, but this is wrong way because i'm writing Hudson plugin.

I need starting point. I need something like [JConsole](http://www.openjdk.org/tools/svc/jconsole/index.html) to integrate in my app and then invoke it when needed or... i just want to manage my app **remotely** via [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the starting points for JMX:

- SUN [tutorial for JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/tutorialTOC.html)
- [Client/Server example](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/connectors.html#wp5529) with JMX (from the same documentation)