# JConsole alternative

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

Does there exists any JConsole alternative which i could bundle with my app ?

Comment: How could i use JConsole ? Only via shell. But it's not the best way... I want to invoke management app directly from my "starter" class

Comment: The link to the JMX tutorial (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859281/jmx-confuseremote-server-control) didn't help?

Comment: It helps - i just researching now to get the best(cleanest) way to implement what i need...

Comment: you can extract required parts from jmanage; web based jmx console: http://www.jmanage.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer but maybe helpful. I just stepped over [one of your last questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798076/create-hudson-plugin) and think, these JConsole/JMX questions are still related to your work on a plugin for the hudson CI. The idea is to have a button on the Hudson UI to start a JConsole or any other managing application.

Thinking about that - Hudson has a web interface. Assume, you use hudson from a remote machine and press your JMX console button, I bet, the console is started on the server and not on the client and therefore inaccessible. So using an existing managing application (java application) limits you plugin to single-workstation uses of hudson. or you go the hard way and integrate not only the launch button but as well a web interface (based on JMX) that allows managing your servers directly from the hudson console.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a command line alternative **Jmxterm** would be a good option.
It almost have all the features Jconsole supports but not the GUI.

Can get it downloaded from [Download JMXTERM Here](http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/cyclops-group/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are happy with running Sun-only classes, you can launch JConsole via

```
java com.sun.jconsole.JConsole
```

and hence directly from your application. Just call JConsole's static `main()` method.

Comment: i could not get aces to JConsole class in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios with nagios-jmx-plugin

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example